# What is Radio logs?

Tags: android, android-logcat, android-debug

I would like to get information on Radio logs in android.Please help me.
As of now i know only the command to view them.i.e adb logcat -b radio.
Where are radio logs used?And why are they used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They wouldn't usually be used by the average user. The radios are related to the mobile network/wifi transmitters/receivers and the logs will provide information about what state they are in, connection issues, signal quality etc.